# what is the actual metaphysical radius for the iOS Multipeer Connectivity Framework?

Tags: ios, iphone, multipeer-connectivity

I've been walking around testing the range and it seems to be about 10 feet but maybe thats my simulator & iPad beta test combo. Apples documentation just says "nearby devices". What it the actual range and would it possible to spread that range to say ...10 miles? This article says iy has no range : http://www.imore.com/multipeer-meshed-networks-and-why-risk-managers-will-love-them

Comment: What is "metaphysical radius"?

Comment: Hard to determine. The answer differs depending on which antenna the framework chooses to use, as well as the broadcast strength of the device, temperature, humidity, etc. The article you linked only claims that there is theoretically no range because Multipeer allows devices to bridge the connection between other devices, so if you had enough people with iPhones standing in a line, you could theoretically extend its range dramatically.

Comment: I have been running directly between an iPad and iPhone at more than 30 m (100 feet). If you have and external WiFi you can of course run at any distance that the network covers.

Comment: It depends on which of the protocols your device decides to use, and unfortunately you have no way of telling it. Unless you turn off one or the other. I have used iPad-to-iPad up to 60m with no problem. Well that's a lie. Since peer-to-peer only work in a stable way doing one-to-one connections, once you keep to that you're OK.

Answer (score 0):

If Apple doesn't tell you the exact range, all you will get from different people will be speculations.

It might be 10 feet for you in your environment, and devices and it could be more for someone with newer devices and quieter signal environment.

Maybe Apple doesn't release the range, because of all these variables, and that it might still be more variable for devices of different models.